# Why does $wpdb->prepare() not pass my query?

Tags: wordpress

Hopefully a quick Wordpress one;

I'm running a db query on a single.php page using the $wpdb class.

My query keeps getting deleted by $wpdb->prepare. It looks like this;

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT post_title, guid
         FROM $wpdb->posts
         WHERE ID IN(" . implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($selected_products),
         '%d')) . ") AND post_status = %s", $selected_products, 'publish');
```

Sorry about the crazy indentation!

If I run this through SQL in PHPMyAdmin it works fine. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

And what about the results from below query,also i didn't see the initialization of `$wpdb`, you should define it as `global`

```
global $wpdb;
$query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_title, guid
         FROM $wpdb->posts
         WHERE ID IN(" . implode(',', array_fill(0, count($selected_products),$selected_products)) . ")
         AND post_status = 'publish' ");
```

Comment: Yeah, I've globalized the $wpdb. Also this query doesn't return a result from the db.

Comment: @glitchmunki what this output says `exit( var_dump( $wpdb->last_query ) );` when you run query in phpmyadmin

Comment: Hey dianuj, I just this second fixed it with a variation of your code above. I just avoided passing the 'publish' string into the query via sprintf...

Comment: @glitchmunki thats gr8 happy coding :)

Comment: If I had needed to pass a variable into $wpdb->prep I would have been knackered. The var_dump returned:

    SELECT p.ID FROM wp_sc53fc_posts AS p  WHERE p.post_date < '2013-09-12 12:54:04' AND p.post_type = 'case-studies' AND p.post_status = 'publish'  ORDER BY p.post_date DESC LIMIT 1' (length=178)